# Does JpaStreamer support Java > 11?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to use JpaStreamer (jpastreamer.org) v3.0.2 with SpringBoot 3.1.1 and Java 17. Doing so, I'm faced with this warning during generation

```
[WARNING] Supported source version 'RELEASE_11' from annotation processor 'com.speedment.jpastreamer.fieldgenerator.StandardFieldGeneratorProcessor' less than -source '17'
```

followed by errors like

```
[ERROR] /{projectpath}/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/mbag/dmiss/entities/ShedlockEntity$.java:[23,9] invalid method reference
  cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method getLockUntil()
    location: class com.mbag.dmiss.entities.ShedlockEntity
```

Just for reference:
I've setup SpringBootApplication like

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.speedment.jpastreamer"})
```

and I've added this Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpastreamer-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa-streamer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer.integration.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-jpastreamer-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa-streamer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Obviously I'm missing something essential, I guess. Right?

Comment: There is even a ticket (https://github.com/speedment/jpa-streamer/issues/333) that has been closed last month where someone now successfully uses JpaStreamer and Spring Boot 3.1 with Java 17, so it definitely should work.